# Sum of days in specific when a specific row is present

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named dbo.build_process. Usually I need to sum the Step Time in Days grouped by Step and this is simple. So, now was requested to to the same but only when step "2_Saw" is available.

| Product | ProductCode | OperatorName | Step | StepSequence | StepDate | StepTimeinDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 0_Start | 0 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 1_Material | 1 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 2_Saw | 2 | 02/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 3_Build | 3 | 03/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 4_Paint | 4 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 5_Varnish | 5 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 6_Packing | 6 | 04/05/2019 | 1 |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 0_Start | 0 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 1_Material | 1 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 3_Build | 3 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 4_Paint | 4 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 5_Varnish | 5 | 02/05/2019 | 1 |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 6_Packing | 6 | 03/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 0_Start | 0 | 03/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 1_Material | 1 | 03/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 2_Saw | 2 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 3_Build | 3 | 04/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 4_Paint | 4 | 05/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 0_Start | 0 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 1_Material | 1 | 04/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 3_Build | 3 | 05/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 4_Paint | 4 | 05/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | 0_Start | 0 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | 1_Material | 1 | 04/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | 3_Build | 3 | 05/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | 4_Paint | 4 | 05/05/2019 | 1 |

When I run the query

```
select 
    Step, 
    sum(StepTimeinDays) as SumofStepTimeinDays
from 
    dbo.build_process
group by 
    Step
order by 
    Step asc
```

The return is:

| Step | SumofStepTimeinDays |
| --- | --- |
| 0_Start | 0 |
| 1_Material | 3 |
| 2_Saw | 1 |
| 3_Build | 2 |
| 4_Paint | 3 |
| 5_Varnish | 1 |
| 6_Packing | 2 |

I need to return the sum to Step Time in Days only for "blocks" where I have the Step 2_Saw:

| Product | ProductCode | OperatorName | Step | StepSequence | StepDate | StepTimeinDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 0_Start | 0 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 1_Material | 1 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 2_Saw | 2 | 02/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 3_Build | 3 | 03/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 4_Paint | 4 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 5_Varnish | 5 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 6_Packing | 6 | 04/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 0_Start | 0 | 03/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 1_Material | 1 | 03/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 2_Saw | 2 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 3_Build | 3 | 04/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 4_Paint | 4 | 05/05/2019 | 1 |

The expected result is:

| Step | Sum of StepTimeinDays |
| --- | --- |
| 0_Start | 0 |
| 1_Material | 1 |
| 2_Saw | 1 |
| 3_Build | 2 |
| 4_Paint | 1 |
| 5_Varnish | 0 |
| 6_Packing | 1 |

I tried to use over partition but couldn't get the expected result.

```
select 
    Step, 
    sum(StepTimeinDays) as SumofStepTimeinDays
from(
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by ProductCode, OperatorName, Step order by StepSequence asc)
    from 
        dbo.build_process
) as t
group by 
    Step
order by 
    Step asc
```

Below the DDL to create the table and populate in SQL Server:

--Create the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[build_process](
    [Product] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [ProductCode] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [OperatorName] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Step] varchar(15) NULL,
    [StepSequence] int NULL,
    [StepDate] date NULL,
    [StepTimeinDays] int NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

--Populate the table

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[build_process] VALUES
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Smith','0_Start',0,'2019-05-02',0),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Smith','1_Material',1,'2019-05-02',0),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Smith','2_Saw',2,'2019-05-02',1),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Smith','3_Build',3,'2019-05-03',1),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Smith','4_Paint',4,'2019-05-04',0),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Smith','5_Varnish',5,'2019-05-04',0),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Smith','6_Packing',6,'2019-05-04',1),
    ('Table','Table_2350','John Doe','0_Start',0,'2019-05-02',0),
    ('Table','Table_2350','John Doe','1_Material',1,'2019-05-02',0),
    ('Table','Table_2350','John Doe','3_Build',3,'2019-05-02',0),
    ('Table','Table_2350','John Doe','4_Paint',4,'2019-05-02',0),
    ('Table','Table_2350','John Doe','5_Varnish',5,'2019-05-02',1),
    ('Table','Table_2350','John Doe','6_Packing',6,'2019-05-03',1),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Doe','0_Start',0,'2019-05-03',0),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Doe','1_Material',1,'2019-05-03',1),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Doe','2_Saw',2,'2019-05-04',0),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Doe','3_Build',3,'2019-05-04',1),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Doe','4_Paint',4,'2019-05-05',1),
    ('Chair','Yellow_Chair','Joseph Smith','0_Start',0,'2019-05-04',0),
    ('Chair','Yellow_Chair','Joseph Smith','1_Material',1,'2019-05-04',1),
    ('Chair','Yellow_Chair','Joseph Smith','3_Build',3,'2019-05-04',0),
    ('Chair','Yellow_Chair','Joseph Smith','4_Paint',4,'2019-05-05',1),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','John Doe','0_Start',0,'2019-05-04',0),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','John Doe','1_Material',1,'2019-05-04',1),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','John Doe','3_Build',3,'2019-05-05',0),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','John Doe','4_Paint',4,'2019-05-05',1)
GO
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @DaleK I edited the question including the DDL to create and populate the table! Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Hi @ThorstenKettner, thank you. I updated the question removing the images.

Comment: Sure the results are wrong in my example 6_Packing, my fault to get correctly values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an `exists` clause to check whether step "2_Saw" exists.

```
select Step
    , sum(StepTimeinDays) as SumofStepTimeinDays
from dbo.build_process t1
where exists (
    select 1
    from dbo.build_process t2
    where t1.ProductCode = t2.ProductCode and t1.OperatorName = t2.OperatorName
    and t2.Step = '2_Saw'
)
group by Step
order by Step asc;
```